# How do I import blob images from oracle database and embed the image at any location of a javamail?

Tags: java, oracle, blob, jakarta-mail, attachment

I am trying to fetch Blob images from database and add them as inline images in mail. But Plain text mail is going without any image. **How can I do that?**

```
EmailContent content
```

contains the BLOB images and the text content.

The function snippet is as follows:

```
public void sendEmail(EmailContent content) throws Exception {

    Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart();

    if (content.getText() != null) {
        MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        multiPart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);

        if (content.getImageContent() != null) {
            MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
            Blob attachmentList = content.getImageContent();
            imagePart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
            imagePart.attachFile((File) attachmentList) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it even possible you are casting `Blob` to a `File`? Assuming it is a `java.sql.Blob` use the `MimeBodyPart` constructor which takes an `InputStream` instead of trying to attach file. `new MimeBodyPart(attementList.getBinaryStream())`; and of course remove the `attachFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write html code to get the image for email part..
I think it will work for you..

```
StringBuilder mailString = new StringBuilder();

applicationURL = https://localhost:8080/xyz + "/images/primary/mailTemplate.jpg";
mailString.append("<html>\n");
mailString.append("     <div style=\"text-align: center;\">\n");
mailString.append("         <img src=");
mailString.append("'");
mailString.append(applicationURL);
mailString.append("'");
mailString.append("align='left'>\n");
mailString.append("     </div>\n");
mailString.append(" </body>\n");
mailString.append("</html><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>");
```

Comment: I am trying to fetch from database. In the above case you are setting a static path to the variable and then adding to the mail body.

Comment: See this [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendmpr).  If you really want to include the image in the message you need to create a multipart/related message.